# Cant set a called parameter inside a asynchronous httpRequests on Parse Cloud Code

Tags: asynchronous, parse-platform

So, i'm having some problems with a Job on javascript Cloud Code. The idea here is to get a bunch of facebook events ids and make a request to facebook API to get the cover photo of these events in a new table (that must have fbEventId as a fk). The problem is that because of the asynchronous requests the ids are not matching with the right cover photos. I know that this is a tricky issue and its giving me some headache on solving.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("updateEventsCoverPhoto", function(request, response) {
  var completedResults = 0;
  var completion = function() {
    response.success("Finished");
  };
  var eventId = [];
  var index = 0;

  var query = new Parse.Query("FbEvent");
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {  
      var totalResults = results.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < totalResults; ++i){
        eventId[i] = results[i].get("fbEventId");

        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
          url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/'+eventId[i]+'/picture?redirect=false&type=large&access_token='+accessToken,
          success: function(httpResponse) {

            for (var key in httpResponse.data) {
              var obj = httpResponse.data[key];

              var FbEventCover = Parse.Object.extend("FbEventCover");
              var fbEventCover = new FbEventCover();
              fbEventCover.set("eventCover", obj["url"]);
              fbEventCover.set("fbEventId", eventId[index]);
              fbEventCover.save(null, {
                success: function(fbEventCover) {
                  console.log('new object created with objectId: ' + fbEvent.id);
                },
                error: function(fbEventCover, error) {
                  console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
                }
              });
            } 
            index++;   
            completedResults++;
            if (completedResults == totalResults) {
              completion();
            }        
          }, error:function(httpResponse){

          }
        });
      }
    },  error: function() {
          completedResults++;
                if (completedResults == totalResults)
                  response.error("Failed to login");
      }
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises to perform several asynch tasks.  If we refactor your code into promise-returning functions, it will greatly simplify.

```
// answer a promise to make the FB request
function eventRequest(eventId, accessToken) {
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/'+eventId+'/picture?redirect=false&type=large&access_token='+accessToken;
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({url:url});
}

// answer a promise to create an FBEventCover
function eventCover(url, eventId) {
    var FbEventCover = Parse.Object.extend("FbEventCover");
    var fbEventCover = new FbEventCover();
    fbEventCover.set("eventCover", url);
    fbEventCover.set("fbEventId", eventId);
    return fbEventCover.save();
}

Parse.Cloud.job("updateEventsCoverPhoto", function(request, response) {
    var eventId = [];
    var query = new Parse.Query("FbEvent");
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        var eventRequests = [];  // an array of promises
        var totalResults = results.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalResults; ++i) {
            eventId[i] = results[i].get("fbEventId");
            eventRequests.push(eventRequest(eventId[i], accessToken));
        }
        // do all the FB requests
        return Parse.Promise.when(eventRequests);
    }).then(function() {
        // results will be in arguments
        var httpResponses = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        var index = 0;
        var eventCovers = [];
        for (var httpResponse in httpResponses) {
            for (var key in httpResponse.data) {
                var obj = httpResponse.data[key];
                eventCovers.push(eventCover(obj.url eventId[index]));
            }
            index++;
        }
        // as before, all of your saves are promises in eventCovers
        return Parse.Promise.when(eventCovers);
    }).then(function() {
        // results will be in arguments
        var completedResults = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        response.success(completedResults);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tested with your code and it seems that the fuction eventCover is not being reached. I dont know why and I don't have any experience using this Promises. Any idea?

Comment: Can you tell if the "then" block after .when(eventRequests) is reached?  The only way I've found to debug the cloud code is a lot of console.log lines at every step.  Hopefully you get the gist of it.   I don't see any alternative but to learn the Promise spec and use it.  Firing off all of those asynch requests from within a loop is sure to not work.